# How to pass multiple arguments when mapping and filtering RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I currently have this line to filter and apply a function to an RDD.

```
data_to_update.rdd.map(find_differences).filter(lambda row: bool(row))
```

I want to modify the `find_differences` function to also take another argument `unique_id` in addition to `row`. I'm not exactly sure how to go about modifying this line to do that, or if there's a better way to write it.

Comment: Use fold operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your cuurent function looks something like this:

```
def find_differences(row):
    # do something
    return result
```

You can create a new function and a partial function that matches your original function:

```
from functools import partial 

def find_differences_id(unique_id, row):
    # do something else
    return another_result

find_differences = partial(find_differences_id, unique_id)
```

And map the RDD as you did before.